# Edit Distance between all the columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, edit-distance

I am interested in calculating the edit distances across all the columns of a given pandas DataFrame. Let's say we have a 3*5 DataFrame - I want to output something like this with the distance scores -  (column*column matrix)

```
  col1  col2 col3 col4 col5
```

col1

col2

col3

col4

col5

I want each element of a column to match with every element of the other columns. Therefore, for every col1*col2 cell = summation of all the scores of the nested loop of col1 and col2.

I would highly appreciate any help in this regards. Thanks in advance.

---

INSPECTION_ID  STRUCTURE_ID  RELOCATE_FID HECO_ID  HECO_ID_TAG_NOT_FOUND  \
0           100         95308           NaN   18/29                    0.0
1           101         95346           NaN  Nov-29                    0.0
2           102      50008606           NaN   25/29                    0.0
3           103         95310           NaN  Dec-29                    0.0
4           104         95286           NaN   17/29                    0.0

OSMOSE_POLE_ID ALTERNATE_ID STREET_NBR STREET_DIRECTIONAL STREET_NAME  \
0             NaN          NaN       1888                NaN   KAIKUNANE
1             NaN          NaN       1731                NaN   MAKUAHINE
2             NaN          NaN       1862                NaN   MAKUAHINE
3             NaN          NaN       1825                NaN   KAIKUNANE
4             NaN          NaN       1816                NaN   KAIKUNANE

Likewise, I got a (191795, 58) dataset. My objective is to find the edit distance between each column of the dataset so as to understand the patterns between them if any.

For instance, I desire INSPECTION_ID  100 to be checked with all the values of column STRUCTURE_ID ans so on. I understand the need of an optimized iterator in this case. Kindly help me throwing some direction to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a small manual example with values so we can have a better feel for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive solution (assuming you already have an edit distance function) but might just work for small datasets

```
df = # your dataset
def edit_distance(s1, s2):
    # some code
    # return edit distance of s1, s2


df_distances = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    row_distances = []
    for item in row:
        for item2 in row:
              row_distances.append(edit_distance(item, item2))
    df_distances.append(some_array)
```

I haven't tested this solution so there might be bugs but the general principle should work. If you don't have an edit distance function, you can use this implementation 
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python or one of the many others freely available

Comment: Hi, my understanding on the above snippet is, this will basically compute the edit distance between the elements of the same row(Different Columns). But I desire to compute the edit distances across all the rows of a given column too. Supposedly we have 3*2 Dataset, I want 9 calculations of edit distances. Hope you would be able to help me around this. Thanks!

Comment: It's still not very clear to me what the goal is. The confusion arises from not knowing exactly what is in each element of the dataframe. It would help if you could provide a small toy dataset and the desired output, I'll change my answer afterwards to address the issue.

Comment: id1, id2, oid ....
0           100         95308           NaN   18/29                    0.0   
1           101         95346           NaN  Nov-29                    0.0   
2           102      50008606           NaN   25/29                    0.0   
3           103         95310           NaN  Dec-29                    0.0   
4           104         95286           NaN   17/29                    0.0   
There you go. I got a (191795, 58) file. I need to find the edit distance between every 2 columns of the file - To understand if any pattern exist with in the columns. Hope this helps.